# Is there any place I can rent or borrow a Megillah from?

Tags: product-recommendation, purim, megillat-esther, transactions, chutz-laaretz

Specifically in or around Brooklyn, NY: I was wondering if anyone knows of a place that rents or lends out Kosher [Megillos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_of_Esther) for Purim.

Comment: You might have better luck the following week.

Comment: An interesting idea for a Gemach!